# Why is my Query within a loop is extremely very slow

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I don't have a enough experience in mysql with php, but am trying to develop a school report card, am trying to query the students, with their exams, subjects and marks. In this case I have three loops. the First loop is for the students I use it to get the student's ID, the second loop is for the exam, i use it to get the exam ID and the last is for subject I use it to get the subject ID, i need all this IDs in order to get the marks for each student per exam per subject. Bellow are the loops;

```
foreach ($students as $student_row){ //get each student's ID
 $studentID = $student_row['studentID'];
       foreach ($allExams as $allExam) { //get each exam's ID
       $examID = $allExam['examID'];
            foreach ($subjects as $subject){ //get each subject's ID
               $subjectID = $subject['subjectID'];

$obtained_mark_query = $this->db->query("select * from mark
            where mark.studentID = '$studentID' && mark.examID = '$examID' && 
            mark.subjectID = '$subjectID'")->row()->mark; //to get mark for each student per exam per subject
                        }

              }

}
```

I don't know what's really the problem but this loop takes really long, it takes 26 second to return all the students in a specific class, there are only 23 students in a class, four exams, and five subjects, so am wondering what it'll really be when there are more than those students. Please any idea why it's behaving like this, any idea i can use other than loops.

Comment: Your doing a query for each iteration of each loop and only using the last result, move the query outside the loops.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 how will i get the the students' marks? remember it has to be for each student per exam per subject.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues in your code's logic:

1. You are selecting every field with `SELECT * FROM` which is highly inefficient, try selecting only the fields you are going to use
2. You are querying in your 3rd nested loop, so instead of querying it once, you are doing 1 query per student, per exam, per subject (like 23 * 4 * 5 = 460 queries)

The solution is to refactor your code, your db, and fetch that information in a simple query, then iterate through the returned records and handle the information server side.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating with the database is very slow. Imagine you're cooking a meal, and your database queries are trips to the grocery store. You wouldn't make a trip for every single ingredient - you'd make a list of all the ingredients you'll need so you can just make a single trip.

So you want to run a single query to fetch all the records you'll need on this page. To make this easier you can turn your "WHERE" clause into the "ORDER BY" of a single query:

```
SELECT * FROM mark ORDER BY studentID, subjectID, examID;
```

Then you can handle the output or any processing of each student's marks one after the other in a single loop over that result set.